# Spark Dataframe: Applying groupBy(over 2 columns).sum(another column) over takes 50GB of space and a lot of time

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by

I am running Scala (2.11.8) based spark (2.0.0) program over an AWS cluster (1 master with 4 worker nodes) with 15gb of memory for each node.

Using the following config to run :

```
spark-submit    --master "spark://ip-xyz:xyz"     --deploy-mode cluster     
   --driver-memory 2g     --executor-memory 10g     --queue default  myProject.jar
```

The dataframe ( df) consists of  " 16098400000 " rows .

```
|    a_id|   i_id|   category|                name|       u|      p|    score|
+--------+-------+-----------+--------------------+--------+-------+---------+
|12000035|8119221|     ARTIST|ASHBY, LINDEN: CA...| 0.01251|0.93166|0.0116613|
|12000081|8119221|     ARTIST|ASHBY, LINDEN: CA...|  0.2672|0.93166| 0.248998|
|12000009|8111111|     ARTIST|ASHBY, LINDEN: CA...|  0.0236|0.93160| 0.022008|
|12000091|8111111|     ARTIST|ASHBY, LINDEN: CA...|     0.5|0.93126|  0.46583|
|13200000|8100000|     ARTIST|ASHBY, LINDEN: CA...|  0.0944|0.93166| 0.088034|
+--------+-------+-----------+--------------------+--------+-------+---------+
```

Running the following code:

```
val df1 = df.groupBy("a_id", "i_id").sum("score")
```

Did a checkpointing with a capacity of 50GB. 
**While monitering the checkpoint, the used space increases from 500mb to 45-50 gb over a period of 2 hours .**

After that the application fails with the error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: No space left on device

I know it's a huge dataset, can I do it efficiently with the same resource?

NOTE: tried groupBy by just 1 column, the operation finished successfully in just 5 minutes.

Comment: can't you keep the grouped table so that you do need only to "sum" when needed?

Comment: @DarioOO If i only group the table first without applying sum, then how do i compute the sum of each grouped row later on?

Comment: using a groupID ?

Comment: @DarioOO , I am new to spark and I tried to find out about the groupID relating to spark or scala , But i couldn't find anything relevant. 
Can you suggest any resource ?